# Meteor - How safe it is?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular, angular-meteor, angular2-meteor

I'm actually creating my first app using meteor, in particular using angular 2. I've experience with Angular 1 and 2, so based on it. I've some points of concern...

Let's imagine this scenario...My data stored on MongoDb:

Collection: clients

```
{
 name : "Happy client",
 password : "Something non encrypted",
 fullCrediCardNumber : "0000 0000 0000 0000"
}
```

Now, on my meteor client folder, I've this struncture...

collection clients.ts (server folder)

```
export var Clients = new Mongo.Collection('clients');
```

component client.ts (not server folder)

```
import {Clients} from '../collections/clients.ts';

class MyClients {
clients: Array<Object>;
constructor(zone: NgZone) {
    this.clients = Clients.find();
    }
}
```

..and for last: the html page to render it, but just display the name of the clients:

```
<li *ngFor="#item of clients">
  {{client.name}}
</li>
```

Ok so far. but my concern is: In angular 1 & 2 applications the component or controller or directive runs on the client side, not server side.

I set my html just to show the name of the client. but since it's ah html rendering, probably with some skill is pretty easy to inject some code into the HTML render on angular to display all my fields.

Or could be easy to go to the console and type some commands to display the entire object from the database collection.

So, my question is: How safe meteor is in this sense ? Does my concerns correct ? Is meteor capable to protect my data , protect the name of the collections ? I know that I can specify on the find() to not bring me those sensitive data, but since the find() could be running not on the server side, it could be easy to modify it on the fly, no ?

Anyway...I will appreciate explanations about how meteor is safe (or not) in this sense.

ty !

Comment: This is a big topic. I'd recommend reading the [security](http://guide.meteor.com/security.html) section of the guide.

Comment: Generally speaking (very generally) you shouldn't be sending data they dont have access to so that if they are malicious they only see data there allowed to see. You client isn't secure ever, so don't trust it to not expose data, perform validation etc.

Comment: Yeah, but bear in mind: You have a client.find() running on the client side...I can put something like client.find(only the fields I wish)...that's ok...but since the find() command will run on the client side, looks easy to anyone to execute something like client.find(everything , including sensitive data) - Looks very easy to execute direct find() MongoDB commands from the client side. I am trying to figure out if my theory is correct or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can protect data by simply not publishing any sensitive data on the server side.

```
Meteor.publish("my-clients", function () {
  return Clients.find({
    contractorId: this.userId   // Publish only the current user's clients
  }, {
    name: 1,    // Publish only the fields you want the browser to know of
    phoneNumber: 1 
  });
});
```

This example only publishes the `name` and `address` fields of the currently logged in user's clients, but not their `password` or `fullCreditCardNumber`.

Another good example is the `Meteor.users` collection. On the server it contains all user data, login credentials, profiles etc. for all users. But it's also accessible on the client side. Meteor does two important things to protect this very sensitive collection:

- By default it only publishes one document: the user that's logged in. If you type `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` into the browser console, you'll only see the currently logged in user's data, and there's no way on the client side to get the entire MongoDB `users` collection. The correct way to do this is to restrict the amount of published documents in your [`Meteor.publish`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) function. See my example above, or 10.9 in the [Meteor publish and subscribe tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe).
- Not the entire user document gets published. For example OAuth login credentials and password hashes aren't, you won't find them in the client-side collection. You can always choose which part of a document gets published, a simple way to do that is using [MongoDB projections](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), like in the example above.

Comment: Hi @aedm ! ty !! I read many articles regarding the users collection. But can I do the same using different collections or does it just apply to users collection ?

Comment: Yes, you can apply the same techniques to all of your collections, and protect them just as well.